# Thread safety java - collection/list

Tags: java, list, sorting, vector, thread-safety

```
List<Integer> contacts = new Vector<Integer>();

Collections.sort(contacts);
```

Okay I know a vector is thread safe, but are there any issues if I do the above?

Comment: what kind of issues?  thread-safety means many things.

Comment: I think you mean: List<Integer> contacts = new Vector<Integer>();
Collections.sort(contacts);
As to thread-safety unless you are storing contacts outside a local variable there is no concern as only one thread can access it.

Comment: Why do you think there would be any thread-safety issue with that code?

Comment: In order for code to be a thread-safety risk, you need more than one thread.  If you have a second thread, and it accesses `contacts` during the sort, then, yes.

Comment: Yeah Apologies never quite read what I typed. And yes of course in different threads.

Answer (score 2):

> vector is thread safe

Each of its methods are thread safe. But `Collections.sort` will iterate over the vector which is not an atomic operation. In particular, [Vector's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) states:

> if the vector is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

So if your vector is modified by another thread while you are sorting it, you will get an exception.

Alternatives if several threads can access your structure include: making a defensive copy or using a concurrent structure such as a CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: Is there a way I could make Collections thread safe or a way to sort it that is?

Comment: The easy way is to make a copy and sort the copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this code thread safe using this:

```
List<Integer> contacts = new Vector<Integer>();

synchronized(contacts) {
  Collections.sort(contacts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Collections.sort(anything) is a very naive thing to do.

If you look at the sort method signatures, you'll see they both operate on Lists, which aren't guaranteed to be thread safe:

`sort(List<T> list) 
sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

Even if you use an old (old in terms of java history) object like Vector, your code becomes risk prone, as the next developer (or perhaps even yourself) may decide to use an ArrayList instead.

sort has destructive behaviour, i.e it is modifying  the underlying collection, and failing to synchronize it may lead you to something like:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
at java.util.ArrayList.sort (...)`

Synchronizing code can be a bit tricky, and the later java implementations provide many features to go around "manually synchronizing" your code.

So what I would do is:

`Collections.sort (Collections.synchronizedList (myList))`